# Will a logic board from a 2009 macbook pro fit and work in a 2006 macbook?

Tags: macbook

I have a [**Apple MacBook Core 2 Duo 2.16 13"**](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.16-white-13-mid-2007-specs.html) and want to know it this will physically fit and work inside the [**Apple MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo 2.26 13"**](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.26-aluminum-13-mid-2009-sd-firewire-800-unibody-specs.html).

Is it worth £100 for the logic board (motherboard) just to get more RAM, a slightly better CPU, and faster read write times?

Comment: If by "logic board" you are referring to the mainboard, then probably not.  Or are you thinking of some a peripheral device on PCMCIA or Expresscard?

Comment: @sawdust "logic board" is Apple-speak for motherboard.

Comment: You'd have to know the measurements of the boards and see whether they're the same. Then there's the power supply, battery connectors, etc. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Thats a lot of effort for a performance increase you might not even notice.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to simply search for images of both motherboards you'd see that they are totally different. They are of different size, port layout, component placement, battery connection, etc etc etc.

Neither motherboard will fit into the other's case.